# Redirect in Application_Error not working in IE & Edge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5, global-asax

I have global written some code to redirect to a custom MVC Action when there is an unhandled error.

This code works fine in Chrome but fails in IE & Edge. IE & Edge are showing their default error page.

Here is my global.asax's Application_Error

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lastException = Server.GetLastError();

        var wrappedContext = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        wrappedContext.Response.StatusCode = (lastException as HttpException)?.GetHttpCode() ?? 500;
        wrappedContext.Response.Clear();
        wrappedContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        wrappedContext.Server.ClearError();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("area", "");
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
        routeData.Values.Add("httpResponseCode", Context.Response.StatusCode);

        IController errorController = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ErrorController>();
            errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(wrappedContext, routeData));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine... The problem was in the view...

Here is the code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Oops, something went wrong...";
    Layout = null;
}

TODO: Nice error page
```

IE & Edge have the following restrictions to display a custom error page ([Table source](https://perishablepress.com/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/)):

[image]

So adding some dummy text to be over 512 bytes made it work...

Don't know why MS did that in IE and more why in Edge?!?